# $(\varphi, \Gamma)$-modules, geometric interpretation $D_{diff}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Could anyone explain to me the first paragraph of page 29 (IV.4.1) of this course of L. Berger:

http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/laurent.berger/articles/article05.pdf

Specifically, I would like to understand what doest "localization at $\epsilon^{(n)} - 1$" mean and what does he mean by glueing solutions to obtain $N_{dR}(V)$. Moreover, I would appreciate any enlightening comments on the geometric interpretation of this theory (such as how these differential operators appeared, etc).